# How to calculate op amp filter cut off frequency?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Here I have a schematic for heart pulse monitor. I am doing a semester work and I can't explain ADCh characteristics step by step.

[image: scheme]

The first passive (high pass) filter I can explain with formula 1/2*pi*R*C.

The second op amp filter (low pass?) I can't explain how it works and I didn't find information for this kind of filter without resistor in parallel. I tried to calculate 1/2*pi*R*C but simulation with MultiSim is quite different with calculated cut off frequency.

Maybe do you have some more information about these filters? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Add component designators to your schematic.

Comment: A day later, and there are *still* no component designators in your schematic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first opamp is set up as a unity gain buffer for AC.  The rolloff frequency between ... argh, no component designators, which makes the circuit hard to talk about.  I'll be less detailed and more general.

Below about 200 Hz, the first opamp stops being a unity gain buffer, with its gain increasing below that.  Put another way, it acts like a comparator at DC, with gain decreasing to 200 Hz, and unit gain beyond that.

The next filter looks like it's meant to pass the edges from the comparator.  It rolls off in gain at about 2.3 Hz, and has 0 gain at DC.

The next capacitor frequency rolloff is with respect to the resistor in parallel with it, not the one you circled.  That rolloff frequency is 3.4 Hz.  At DC, the gain is 470, decreasing to the rolloff frequency, and unity gain above that.

Comment: Thank you! But can you tell me how I should calculate these frequencies? And about 8.2kOhm resistor? Why 8.2? Thank you a lot!